# htaccess: rewrite url from one domain/folder to a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have two domains parked with a common site. For a particular folder path, we need to make sure one of the domains is always used. I need a rewrite rule that will direct to the correct domain only when a certain folder (and it's children) are accessed.

http://www.domain1.com/admin/
redirects to
http://www.domain2.com/admin/

I will need to accommodate the possibility that first url could be:
http://domain1.com/admin/  (i.e. either root domain or www form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^admin.* http://www.domain2.com/$0 [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.

Comment: beautiful -- thanks. I had something similar but wasn't handling the subdirectory correctly.